# Mahout Random Forest Data Description Error

Tags: hadoop, mahout, random-forest

While trying to run the [Mahout Random Forest Descriptor](https://mahout.apache.org/users/stuff/partial-implementation.html) I am getting this following error.
P.S.: I am trying to run on a different set (not the one provided on the link)
The descriptor used is:

```
hadoop jar /home/ubuntu/binaries/mahout-distribution-0.9/mahout-core-0.9-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe -p /user/ubuntu/train_OLwoCV.csv -f  /user/ubuntu/train_OLwoCV.csv.info -d L 3 N 5 C N 2 C N C N
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data.DescriptorException: Bad Token : 2ï¿½C
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data.DescriptorUtils.parseDescriptor(DescriptorUtils.java:55)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data.DataLoader.generateDataset(DataLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe.generateDataset(Describe.java:127)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe.runTool(Describe.java:115)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe.main(Describe.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Grep is not able to help me. Is it some issue with the data or my description of the data?

Comment: is your data encoding ok (e.g. UTF8)? Are there any non-latin characters?

Comment: the output of `file -bi` is as:
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ file -bi 21Mar2014/train_OLwoCV.csv`
`text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Comment: And while I go through the data, I do not find any unwanted formatted data values either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to double check that descriptor option ('-d L 3 N 5 C N 2 C N C N') is fitting your data well, because DescriptorException("Bad Token : " + token) can throw if descriptor not found for some column in csv.

**code for parseDescriptor() method from Mahout v0.7:**

```
public static Attribute[] parseDescriptor(CharSequence descriptor) throws DescriptorException {

 List<Attribute> attributes = Lists.newArrayList();
 for (String token : SPACE.split(descriptor)) {
   token = token.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
   if ("I".equals(token)) {
     attributes.add(Attribute.IGNORED);
   } else if ("N".equals(token)) {
     attributes.add(Attribute.NUMERICAL);
   } else if ("C".equals(token)) {
     attributes.add(Attribute.CATEGORICAL);
   } else if ("L".equals(token)) {
     attributes.add(Attribute.LABEL);
   } else {
     throw new DescriptorException("Bad Token : " + token);
   }
 }
return attributes.toArray(new Attribute[attributes.size()]);
}
```